# To what extent can we depend on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on a project and trying to use JavaScript for validating all inputs that are entered by a user before inserting into the database.

Can we depend entirely on JavaScript for user input validation?

Comment: No! Always validate user input on the server as well. You can use JavaScript validation just to provide some quick feedback to the user, but *always* validate it on the server too.

Comment: Please, search for duplicated questions! you're not the first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; you emphatically must not.
Attackers can disable Javascript.

Attackers can even send raw HTTP requests so that Javascript doesn't enter the picture in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can make requests to your server without even using a browser, let alone javascript. You cannot **depend** on javascript for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Now, 3 years after this question was asked I'd like to add an answer.
All answers are assumig that the validating Javascript is running on the client (which was probably also the case at that time).

Nowadays, Javascript can also be the language used on the server.
And in that case it is perfectly ok. Attackers cannot disable that part.

But the main point addressed by the other answers remains valid: relying on data validation on the client side only cannot be allowed.

.